# How can I put a floating div to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, positioning, css-float

I have a web page with a "header", a content with two columns and a "footer". The content left column or "contentinfo" has variable size because it depends on the information loaded. The right column or "sidebar" has two different divs in it, one with a "menu" and other with "credits".

Something like:

```
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="contentinfo" style="float:left;"></div>
<div id="sidebar" style="float:right;">
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="credits"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer" style="clear:both;">
```

You can see a sketch: (The "sidebar" is just a container div)

[image: sketch]

What I want is to put the "credits" div aligned at the bottom of the "contentinfo" div. And let the space between the "Menu" div and the "credits" div empty. Something like:

[image: desired]

I have tried to set position:relative; in the "sidebar" and position:absolute; bottom:0px; in the "credits". The problem is that I can't set an specific height to the "sidebar" because I don't know the height of the "contentinfo". However, in a trial, I've set the side bar height to a high enough value and the code didn't work.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm new here so I don't know if I made something wrong. An answer appeared and disappeared. However it didn't solve my problem because of the variable size of my "contentinfo" div.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: what would make it easier is if you added some code for us to look at and edit. To add code to your post simply add 4 spaces before each line of code (including blank lines in you code)

Comment: ¡I made it! It is a bit amateurish but it works:

I put the "credits" under the "footer" with a height:100px; and a position:absolute; top:-100px;

In the side bar i added a "slot" empty div with height:100px. In that way I avoid collisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡I made it! It is a bit amateurish but it works:

I put the "credits" under the "footer" with a height:100px; and a position:absolute; top:-100px;

In the side bar i added a "slot" empty div with height:100px. In that way I avoid collisions.

You can see it in http://blog.tomtucker.cz.cc

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">Header</div>

<div id="contentinfo" style="float:left;">Content</div>
<div id="sidebar" style="float:right;">
    <div id="menu">Menu</div>
    <div id="slot" style="height:100px">Slot</div>
    <!-- With that I avoid overlapping with the credits -->
</div>

<div id="footer" style="clear:both; position:relative;">Footer
    <div id="credits">Credits</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    width:600px;
}

#header {
    background-color:#F00;
    height:30px;
    width:600px;
}

#contentinfo {
    background-color:#CCC;
    height:600px; /* Any you want*/
    width:500px;
    float:left;
}

#sidebar {
    width:100px;
    float:right;
}

#menu {
    background-color:#00F;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
}

#slot {
    background-color:#0F0;
    width:!00%;
    height:100px; /* The same as the credits div */
}

#footer {
    background-color:#FF0;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    height:30px;
    width:600px;
}

#credits {
    background-color:#609;
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    top:-100px;
    left:500px;
}
```